# How to detect single-digit numbers with Firebase ML Kit on Android?

Tags: android, firebase, text-recognition, firebase-mlkit

I have followed the setup guide for the [Firebase ML Kit on Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/android/recognize-text) and created a simple app that can recognize text on bitmap images, using the on-device text recognizer. It works pretty well out of the box, but there is one case where it doesn't seem to work: recognizing single-digit numbers.

In this image it recognizes all the numbers with more than one digit, but none of the single-digit numbers.

[image]

When I debug the returned FirebaseVisionText object, I see 12, 10, 45%, 10 and 83%, but not the 6, 2, 0, 0, 0 and 2.

I'm using the ocr model (defined in the manifest):

```
 <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.ml.vision.DEPENDENCIES"
        android:value="ocr" />
```

Is there any other model or some configuration I can change, to allow the text recognizer to detect the single-digit numbers?

Comment: I have the same issue with this format: XXX-XXX-X (it ignores most of the times -not always- the last dash and number)

Comment: Did you find a way to go ahead ?

Comment: @Kaizie : did you found a way to solve this problem

Comment: Nope... 95% of the times it will not see the last digit if it is only one digit. I can understand that when you scan just 1 digit it may not know you are trying to find a digit, but when i scan a full bunch of numbers, and it just ignores the last one... it is very annoying.